# Dollar sign in fields after proguarding in Android

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I have a class that gets dollar sign with random hex string after proguarding.

Before proguard:

```
public class MyClass<D extends Params, S extends Params, B extends Slots> extends Params<D, S> {
    private B slots;
}
```

After proguard:

```
public class MyClass<D extends g, S extends g, B extends g> extends Params<D, S> {
  private B slots$41652c7
}
```

How prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `keepclassmembers` rule following this format and Proguard will not do anything with the fields in the class.

```
-keepclassmembers class MyClass {
    private <fields>;
}
```

Please note that Proguard requires the class reference to be a fully-qualified namespace.